# Is it possible to angle a input field and textarea with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Has anyone figured out how to angle a text field in a form?  I'm tired of perfectly straight horizontal fields and I would like experiment with something different.  I don't want to use flash.

A little tilt action please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like what's described [here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation).

From that site:

> For Webkit and Firefox (as of 3.5),
>   you can take advantage of the proposed
>   transform property to handle the
>   rotation. Each browser requires its
>   property prefix for now.
>
> ```
> -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
> -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
> ```

For IE:

> When it comes to effects in Internet
>   Explorer, there is a surprising amount
>   of power (and untapped at that, I'd
>   say) in using filters. Although
>   misleading, there is a filter called
>   BasicImage that offers up the ability
>   to rotate any element that has layout.
>
> ```
> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
> ```

Comment: When you mean prefix, is IE hopeless here?

Comment: Updated answer... Check out the linked site-- has more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/rotation.htm

Or use SVG with an embedded HTML.